# We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this content

Tags: magento2

On the home page instead of displaying blocks displays:

```
We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this content.
```

Any solution?

in debug.log

```
[2018-04-02 08:31:45] main.CRITICAL: Cannot read contents from file "/home/fsg/domains/wearon.pl/public_html/pub/static/frontend/Mgs/claue/cs_CZ/mage/requirejs/mixins.min.js" Warning!file_get_contents(/home/fsg/domains/wearon.pl/public_html/pub/static/frontend/Mgs/claue/cs_CZ/mage/requirejs/mixins.min.js): failed to open stream: No such file or directory {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): Cannot read contents from file \"/home/fsg/domains/wearon.pl/public_html/pub/static/frontend/Mgs/claue/cs_CZ/mage/requirejs/mixins.min.js\" Warning!file_get_contents(/home/fsg/domains/wearon.pl/public_html/pub/static/frontend/Mgs/claue/cs_CZ/mage/requirejs/mixins.min.js): failed to open stream: No such file or directory at /home/fsg/domains/wearon.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:149)"} []
[2018-04-02 08:31:50] main.CRITICAL: Cannot read contents from file "/home/fsg/domains/wearon.pl/public_html/pub/static/frontend/Mgs/claue/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.min.js" Warning!file_get_contents(/home/fsg/domains/wearon.pl/public_html/pub/static/frontend/Mgs/claue/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.min.js): failed to open stream: No such file or directory {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): Cannot read contents from file \"/home/fsg/domains/wearon.pl/public_html/pub/static/frontend/Mgs/claue/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.min.js\" Warning!file_get_contents(/home/fsg/domains/wearon.pl/public_html/pub/static/frontend/Mgs/claue/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.min.js): failed to open stream: No such file or directory at /home/fsg/domains/wearon.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:149)"} []
```

Comment: cms home page check any custom block call in page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your error logs what error it says some time this error occurs when there is change in db. run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and `php bin/magento cache:flush`

enable / set developer mode ( if not already ) to set developer mode in your htaccess file. Uncomment

```
SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer
```

or / also you can run below command in CLI :

```
php ./bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

So you can see which section / block is causing the issue.
Hope above steps will help to figure out the issue and help you to fix it.

Comment: I have checked log file and update my topic.

Comment: have you deployed static content after installation of extension ? ( first delete your pub/static/frontend and var/view_processed/pub folder content and then try again).

Comment: I have migrate magento on second server and after migrate display this error. I have try delete pub/static.. etc and deployed again but still no work.

Comment: disable "Mgs" module and then try again.

Comment: MGS created the template and its all modules magento working.

Comment: disable that module and try running your site again if it works or not, that way you will know if this module is creating issue or there is something else..

Comment: Block instagram generated problem. I have enable page builder and delete insagram block - now all works.

Answer (score 0):

In magento 2.3.3 version

you can add the

```
'static_content_on_demand_in_production' => 1,
```

```
in evn.php file after date.
```

Its working perfect.

See below link

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6426